# bibliography producing extra number at the end

Tags: bibtex, natbib

When I compile my document, I get an extra number at the end. How can I get round to work on actually citation and remove the superfluous `(1)`?
[image]

`.bib`

```
@online{BLS,
            author = {Bureau of Labor Statistics Handbook, 2016-17 Edition},
            title = {Computer and Information Research Scientists},
            url = {http://www.bls.gov/ooh/computer-and-information-technology/computer-and-information-research-scientists.htm},
            month = {Dec},
            year = {2015},
            note = "[Online; accessed 22 July 2016]"
            }
```

> **MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}


\author{John Doe}
\title{Title}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\abstractname{Name}
\abstract
Abstract

\section{test}
test

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\cite{BLS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want `\nocite{*}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert the `\cite{}` command at the position you want it to be cited. If you insert it after the '\bibliography', it will include it here and cause the (1) afterwards!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}


\author{John Doe}
\title{Title}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\abstractname{Name}
\abstract
Abstract

\section{test}
test\cite{BLS}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{test}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The numbers are then at the top and not the bottom

Comment: Okay, what are you exactly looking for? The (1) is deleted afterwards and is inserted in the text. Isn't this what you are looking for? You have to include it somewhere, otherwise it won't be cited in the '\bibliography'...

Comment: Just to populate the references. Without saying cite, the references come up blank

Comment: So I just edited my answer. The image now shows, how it looks like in my editor. And you want to delete the (1) after 'test'?